# Unsupported Media Type Did not attempt to load JSON data because the request Content-Type was not 'application/json'

Tags: python, json, flask, python-requests

Yes, I know I've seen a lot of different answers to this question, but either I was looking badly, or it just wasn't for my situation.
So
My script in html:

```
fetch('/AddPosition', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                initData: tg.initData,
            })
          });
```

My Flask:

```
@app.route('/AddPosition', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def AddPosition():
    if request.method == "POST":
        data = request.json
        print(data)
        init_data = parse_init_data(token=config.BOT_TOKEN, raw_init_data=data['initData'])
        if init_data is False:
            return False
    return render_template('AddPosition.html')
```

And my webhook setting:

```
@app.post(f"{config.WEBHOOK_PATH}")
def process_webhook_post():
    if request.headers.get('content-type') == 'application/json':
        json_string = request.get_data().decode('utf-8')
        update = types.Update.de_json(json_string)
        bot.process_new_updates([update])
        return ''
    else:
        abort(403)
```

I tried:

```
    return render_template('AddPosition.html', mimetype="application/json")
```

And I was playing with 'Accept': 'application/json' and 'Content-Type': 'application/json'

Update:

```
@app.route('/AddPosition', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def AddPosition():
    if request.method == "POST":
        if request.headers.get('Content-Type') == 'application/json':
            print(999)
```

It's work (print 999).
Why I still getting this error??

Comment: Rendering an HTML template seems rather unlikely to produce JSON data.  Why are you trying to claim that it is JSON?

Comment: @jasonharper I followed this code https://github.com/abdullaev388/Telegram-Web-App/blob/master/telebot_webapp/main.py